# MUI Theme provider button override not applying

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, themes

I'm trying to add a custom background color, font weight and font size to my mui button using the global theme provider. However when I add the changes they aren't showing, with the button still having the default background, font size and weight.

Here is my function for the theme:

```
function getDesignTokens(mode:PaletteMode) {
    return {
        palette: {
            mode,
            ...(mode === 'light'
                ? {
                    // palette values for light mode
                }
                : {
                    // palette values for dark mode
                    components: {
                        MuiButton: {
                            styleOverrides: {
                                contained: {
                                    backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(to right, #74d9eb, #8fb0c7)',
                                    '&:hover': {
                                        backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(to right, #74d9eb, #8fb0c7)',
                                    }
                                },
                                root: {
                                    fontWeight: '700',
                                    fontSize: '15px',
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }),
        },
    }
}
```

Page code where the theme should in theory be applied

```
function Contact() {
    const themeHook = useTheme();
... rest of component code
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={themeHook.theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Send
            </Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

All the changes are on my Github where you can try to replicate the issue

[Page component](https://github.com/bracesproul/Portfolio/blob/main/src/pages/Contact/index.tsx)

[Hook](https://github.com/bracesproul/Portfolio/blob/main/src/hooks/useTheme/index.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hill-qcz4b9?file=/Theme.tsx)
Seems you had to change the `backgroundColor` to `background`

```
components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontWeight: "700",
          fontSize: "15px"
        },
        contained: {
          background: "linear-gradient(to right, #74d9eb, #8fb0c7)",
          "&:hover": {
            background: "linear-gradient(to right, red, blue)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```